# jQuery autocomplete: I need to use spacebar to select item

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I need to select the item in the suggestion list of jQuery autocomplete with the space bar instead with the return key.

Can I do that easily?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the **jQueryUI Autucomplete Plugin** you can modify the source code to get your desired effect. Line `7151` has the following code:

```
    case keyCode.ENTER:
    // when menu is open and has focus
    if ( this.menu.active ) {
    // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
    // which causes forms to submit
        suppressKeyPress = true;
        event.preventDefault();
        this.menu.select( event );
    }
```

To remove this functionality, assuming you do not want any events tied to `keydown` + `ENTER`, you can comment it out or delete the code. I would comment it out, in case you want to add something later.

Line `6672` has the following empty `case` within the `keyup` `switch` statement:

```
case keyCode.SPACE:
```

You can add the commented out code to this section, and you should now be able to select items with the `SPACE` rather than enter:

```
 case keyCode.SPACE:

   if ( this.menu.active ) {

      suppressKeyPress = true;
      event.preventDefault();
      this.menu.select( event );
   }
```